# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0, but Angular version 15.1.4 was found instead

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, build, angular-cli

build issue in ionic angular app

Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.8
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.5.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 15.1.5
@angular/cli                  : 15.1.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2, browser 7.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
native-run (update available: 1.7.2)   : 1.7.1

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v16.14.2
npm               : 9.4.2
OS                : Windows 10

couldn't figure out the issue here

Comment: I looks like ionic angular v6 just supports to angular 14, if you want to use angular 15 or higher you need to use ionic v7